# Trying to make these divs not reset position when I add new one with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have tried changing the `keyup` part of the code to a `button` and I have also tried some code to get the draggable element to store its position in the cookie but to no avail. When I change the empty tag to ready it repeats the previous lines every time. Any help would be much appreciated.

[jsFiddle for original code](http://jsfiddle.net/fergusp/6NB6c/)

[jsFiddle for my attempt at a button](http://jsfiddle.net/fergusp/6NB6c/8)

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="opt"></div>
```

CSS

```
d {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").keyup(splitLine);

    function splitLine() {
        $("#opt").empty();
        var lines = $("textarea").val().split(/\n/g);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var ele = $("<d>");
            ele.html(lines[i]);
            $("#opt").append($(ele).draggable());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not reset position"?  I played with the button version a little and it seems to be working, but I am not sure what the "not reset position" part means. http://jsfiddle.net/sdDDx/

Comment: @patrick Yeah it does but it creates all the lines as new divs creating duplicates. not sure how to get this to stop? making duplicates that is, so just add the last line of the text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't remove all your `<d>` and start over every time. I have made some changes in the code to reuse the old `<d>` so that it's position is preserved

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("textarea").keyup(splitLine);

  function splitLine() {
    //$("#opt").empty();
    var lines = $("textarea").val().split(/\n/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      var ele;
      if ($("d:eq(" + i + ")").get(0)) {
        ele = $("d:eq(" + i + ")");
        ele.html(lines[i]);
      } else {
        ele = $("<d>");
        ele.html(lines[i]);
        $("#opt").append($(ele).draggable());
      }
    }
  }
});
```